# Hold button+[a-z] to immediately trigger ace-jump+[a-z]?

Tags: key-bindings

Currently I have to press some modifier combo + letter to trigger ace jump with letter. This is obnoxiously time-consuming for a command I use all the time.

I want to be able to just hold down a key (æ in my case) and press "s" (like I'd do shift-s to write capital S) to trigger ace-jump for s. And so on for the other letters.

The main problem is taking a general letter and triggering the command for that letter, I presume. (I could probably have come up with a hard-coded solution myself and will be hesitant to accept one as an answer.)

PS. ace-jump tag missing.

Comment: Use `(event-basic-type last-command-event)` in your command ?

Comment: So is your question "how can I use a non-modifier key as a modifier key?"

Comment: Event-basic type will give me the letter it seems. Will play around with it to understand it properly.

Comment: @Dan perhaps to some degree. Ace-jump is a command that is not meant to be used with a modifier, so it is rather how do I convert/call a command that is not meant to be used with a modifier to one that does.

Comment: I might do this on an OS level rather, by making the desired mod key trigger the neccessary prefix combo within emacs.

Comment: Seems like the new `avy` can work non-interactively: `(defun avy-goto-lp ()
  (interactive)
  (avy-goto-char ?\())` It seems much nicer than ace-jump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simulate <kbd>æ</kbd> as a modifier using `key-chord`. I don't have an <kbd>æ</kbd> key, so I'll demonstrate with <kbd>q</kbd>

```el
(key-chord-mode +1)
(dolist (key (number-sequence 0 255))
  (lexical-let ((key-saved key))
    (key-chord-define-global (vector ?q key)
      (lambda ()
        (interactive)
        (avy-goto-char key-saved)))))
```

If you plan on always holding <kbd>æ</kbd> first, you may be interested in this variant:

```el
(key-chord-mode +1)
(dolist (key (number-sequence 0 255))
  (lexical-let ((key-saved key))
    (global-define-key (vector 'key-chord ?q key)
      (lambda ()
        (interactive)
        (avy-goto-char key-saved)))))
```